# Cucumber/Capybara link testing using array and loops

Tags: ruby, arrays, hyperlink, cucumber, capybara

I'm very new to cucumber/capybara/ruby, trying BDD on a php-built website.

### Checking on:

Different links directs a user to the correct page on : "prod-integration-mycompany.com"

### Situation:

on this page I've got some unique links(around 20 to 50) and the links look something like,

> ```
> <a href= " /edition/123456"> BookTitle 01 by <a class="author" title= "Dan Romio" href=" >/author/Dan+Romio/112212">Dan Romio</a>'
>
> <a href= " /edition/654321"> BookTitle 02 by <a class="author" title= "Maggi Smith" href=" >/author/Maggi+Smith/11332">Maggi Smith</a>
>
> <a href= " /edition/56232"> BookTitle 03 by <a class="author" title= "Dan Romio" href=" >/author/Dan+Romio/112212">Dan Romio</a>
> etc…
> ```

### What I want to check:

I want to check when a user clicks on an edition link, the  of that page matches BookTittle. I can do it one by one on my steps

> ```
>    When ……
>        within(:css, 'dd[@id = "(css ID here)"]') do
>       click_on '' or click_link (name of the link)
>         end 
>    end
>
>    Then ………|text|
>         check_destination(text)
>    end
> ```

on env.rb, I've got some functions like "check_destination()" and different asserts:

> ```
>       def check_destination(paramText)
>       new_window = page.driver.browser.window_handles.last
>       page.within_window new_window do
>             path = URI.parse(current_url)
>            assert_include(paramText,path)
>         end
>       end
> ```

### So ? What's the problem ?:

Problem is when I wanna do a whole bunch of them, I don't know how I'm gonna use array's key=> value and loop through them on my steps. Is it Table, is it class, I kind of running out of concept/ideas here…any idea ? link ? And btw sorry if I waste your time. Thanks.

Comment: Is there actually value in checking each of those links (ie if one of those links works, what is the likelihood that one of the other links breaks)?

Comment: @JustinKo: it might be a case of edition id does/does not  exist or even if it's exist might be a redis(cache) issue. I wouldn't say a great value in checking those links, but I can use the same logic in different situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am so so dumb..... I could've just use page.all on node finders, using option will let me do whatever I wanna do.
http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders

```
    within("within block here") do 
        element = page.all("specify the condition to get all the elements")
        puts element.count  # should provide no of elements
    end
```

First element can be access by element[0]."some method here"

All the list of method can be found in: http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/c/capybara-rails-2-2-0.4.1.1/Capybara/Node/Element.html